# Reading onboard-RTC registers of STM32F411

Tags: c, stm32f4, rtc, stm32cubemx, stm32f4-discovery

I am trying to read the values in the seconds register of on board RTC of the STM32f411E discovery board. I want to transmit the values to my serial port. I believe i have initialized the hardware correctly (RTC, USART for displaying values on PC), but somehow i need to press the reset button if i have to see the updated seconds values. The values seem to be plausible (0-59 in BCD format), but i do not know what am i doing wrong that i need to reset?

Host OS: Linux (Ubuntu 64-bit),

Target: STM32F411E-DISCO,

Controller: STM32F411VET6U,

Tool-chain used: MxCube, SWSTM32 IDE based on eclipse, ST-Link Utility to flash the bin file.

Here is my code:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : main.c
  * Description        : Main program body
  **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h"

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
RTC_HandleTypeDef hrtc;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_RTC_Init(void);
//static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}


int main(void)
{

  RTC_TimeTypeDef st_time;
  uint8_t sec=0;

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();


  /*Initialise USART2*/
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  HAL_UART_MspInit(&huart2);
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

  /*Initialise RTC*/
  MX_RTC_Init();
  HAL_RTC_MspInit(&hrtc);
  HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc);   

  while (1)
  {


      HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &st_time, RTC_FORMAT_BCD);
      HAL_Delay(5);
      sec=st_time.Seconds;
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2 ,&sec , 1,100);
      HAL_Delay(400);



  }


}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 192;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 8;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_RTC;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSI;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* RTC init function */
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime;
  RTC_DateTypeDef sDate;

    /**Initialize RTC Only 
    */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_12;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date 
    */
  if(HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR0) != 0x32F2){
  sTime.Hours = 0x1;
  sTime.Minutes = 0x0;
  sTime.Seconds = 0x0;
  sTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  sTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sDate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  sDate.Month = RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
  sDate.Date = 0x1;
  sDate.Year = 0x4;

  if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc,RTC_BKP_DR0,0x32F2);
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();


}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char * file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */ 
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here, Page 719:

http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/2f/71/ba/b8/75/54/47/cf/DM00105879.pdf/files/DM00105879.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105879.pdf

For those of you who wants to use this module, keep in mind:

> You must call HAL_RTC_GetDate() after
>   HAL_RTC_GetTime() to unlock the values in the higher-order
>   calendar shadow registers to ensure consistency between the
>   time and date values. Reading RTC current time locks the
>   values in calendar shadow registers until Current date is read.

Called the `HAL_RTC_GetDate()` right after Get_Time and it worked.